# How to make gradle use an older android build tool than 19.1.0

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I'm trying to aim to an old Android device (4.2.2). So far I installed everything cordova demanded everytime I input `cordova run android`. Although `sdkmanager --list` displays 19.1.0 as the the oldest build-tools, I did get the 17.0.0 build tools by trying `sdkmanager --install build-tools;17.0.0`.

I'm determined to use it. Although, as expected, Gradle won't stop complaining by printing out:

> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

#### My software specs are:

- Microsoft Windows 7 64 bits
- Cmder (terminal)
- NodeJS 10.13.0 (npm 6.4.1)
- Cordova 8.1.2
- Gradle 4.10.2
- sdkmanager 26.1.1

#### Installed platforms (`cordova platform list`)

- android 6.4.0
- browser 5.0.4

Comment: You can build with 28.0.3 and still install your app on an API 17 device. Just set your `minSdkVersion` to 17.

Comment: @TheWanderer Given my setup, where am I supposed to edit the `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I only know the Gradle build system, but there must be a way to specify your minimum supported API.